# Sets of exterior measure zero are necessarily measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\mu_*$ is an exterior measure and the definition of a Caratheodory measurable set, $E$, is that for any $A \in X$,$\;\;$ $\mu_*(A)=\mu_*(E\cap A)+\mu_*(E^c\cap A)$

My book makes the remark that say that all sets of exterior measure zero are measurable and that this remark is immediate from the definition. Could someone explain to me why this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the subadditivity of $\mu_{\ast}$ we have

$$\mu_{\ast}(A) \leqslant \mu_{\ast}(A\cap E) + \mu_{\ast}(A\setminus E)$$

whatever set $E$ is. If $\mu_{\ast}(E) = 0$, then by monotonicity ($A\cap E \subseteq E$) of $\mu_{\ast}$ we also have $\mu_{\ast}(A\cap E) = 0$ and hence, once more by monotonicity ($A \setminus E \subseteq A$),

$$\mu_{\ast}(A\cap E) + \mu_{\ast}(A \setminus E) = \mu_{\ast}(A\setminus E) \leqslant \mu_{\ast}(A) \leqslant \mu_{\ast}(A\cap E) + \mu_{\ast}(A\setminus E),$$

so equality overall.